# Rename Multiple Installations of Eclipse to Distinguish them in OS X Doc

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have several installations of Eclipse for different type development.  In the past I've just renamed Eclipse.app to "Eclipse Juno STS JDK 1.7.app".  Its a leaky solution, because an Eclipse.app gets created next to it, but today after updating one of my plugins, Eclipse would no longer start.

Is there a better way to have different names for multiple Eclipse Installations is OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer at the bottom of this [thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299955).

After renaming Eclipse.app to "Eclipse Juno STS JDK 1.7.app", create a link named "Eclipse.app" to help redirect plugins hardcoded to look for Eclipse.app:

```
rename Eclipse.App "Eclipse Juno STS JDK 1.7.app"
ln -s "Eclipse Juno STS JDK 1.7.app" Eclipse.app
```